# file is not defined in Javascript when reading local file

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first styled page</title>
</head> 
<body>

<script> 
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
var text = reader.result;
document.querySelector('body').append(text);
};
reader.readAsText(README, "us-ascii");
</script>

<!-- Site navigation menu -->
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="alamode-fetch">Alamode</a>
<li><a href="README">Readme</a>
<li><a href="town.html">My town</a>
<li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
</ul>

<!-- Main content -->
<h1>My first styled page</h1>
<p>Welcome to my styled page!
<p>It lacks images, but at least it has style.And it has links, even if they       don't go anywhere&hellip;
<p>There should be more here, but I don't know what yet.
<!-- Sign and date the page, it's only polite! -->
<address>Made 5 April 2004<br> 
by myself.
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my html file. I was trying to reading the local file named as README. When I execute my html file, looks like there is nothing happened with my javascript. And I found that in the firefox, it reminds that README is not defined. I have stuck on it for whole day....

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22033170/2827823

Comment: I tried it. Not working....not sure what's going on with it...

Comment: If you read my link thoroughly (and understand it), you will see what/how to do

Comment: Yes, I read it carefully and tried. There is no error in Firefox. But still nothing different. What I am concerning is that maybe either my Firefox or Linux has issue.

Comment: That might be, so I guess next step for you is to debug every line of your js code and check the relevance of each variable/value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is `README`. Javascript expect README will be a variable but you don't define it.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText

Comment: I still didn't get it. Can you tell me more please?